# Does the Srivaishnavite sect say that Vishnu created Chaturmukha Brahma?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma

Siva is said to have incurred sin by cutting off Brahma's fifth head.  The Srivaishnavite sect accepts this and if I recall correctly, some Vaishnavite temples in the South have sthalapuranams that say that Siva got rid of his sin by praying to the deity of the temple.

Do Srivaishnavite scriptures say that Vishnu created Chaturmukha Brahma?

How do they reconcile that account with Brahma originally starting with five heads?

Comment: He created whom you *currently know* as Chaturmukha Brahma. Like people say 'Vishvamitra's penance was disturbed by Indra' - we know it was Kaushika trying to do penance, before he got title of Vishvamitra. But Kaushika is not a popular name. So it means *'The person who u currently know as Vishvamitra had his penance disturbed by Indra'*

Comment: the whole story is symbolic..cutting of fifth head by siva who is son of brahma.. is not possible.. because the taratamya tree.. Lakshmi Narayana->Brahma, Vayu->Saraswathi, Bharathi -> Garuda, Sesha and Rudra. So Rudra is in 5 level from the top..

Comment: Cutting of head of brahma. .is cutting of Tamo guna from brahma.. so brahma is pure sattva guna.. Tamo guna abhimani is shiva its shiva himself cuts off his head..

Comment: one had to remember mahir ravana story where Hanuman with five facess blows the lamp in five direction at the same  time..  The present Hanuman is eligible ot become brahma in another cycle.. so he is said of five faces as with Hanuman who is original Pancha mukhi.

Comment: @Prasanna R you are stating the views of one (tiny minority, numerically) sect as the views of all Hindus.  On top of it, you are citing views that insult a deity beloved of hundreds of millions of Hindus

Comment: @SK i got where you are from, but its not degrading any devatha sakthi Lord Shiva is vaishnavottama among devthas other than brahma,vayu, sarswathi,bharathi, garuda and sesha.. but if you take it other way im not responsible.

Comment: For your question i have answered why brahma was having 5 faces by relating with Hanuman i.e.Vayu @SK There are several stories like this which are symbolic one need to extract spiritual meaning from them to make any sense.

Comment: if you are tamil by any chance why veda is called NanMarai? why its not NanThelivu in tamil?

Comment: So your sect even begrudges Siva the "foremost vaishnava" title in Bhagavata Purana.  Amazing.  @prasanna R.

Comment: See This what tartamya tree tells  that directly relates 24 tattvas of jiva, prakruthi  or whatever universe is defined.. But im not here to convince you either. I just put what madhvaites view on the above. There is no need to bregrudges any devatha sakthi for that matter.. it was from vedas and puranas it was taken like Rudra was son of brahma inother words Shiva

Comment: I find the "promotions" and "demotions" of gods after the foundational Rig Veda a source of amusement only @prasanna R